# Values not getting inserted into matrix

Tags: python, list

Am trying to build a matrix from scratch using Python Lists in Hackerrank.
The problem is that the code is running fine in sublime text but not in Hackerrank console.
It's showing this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 8, in <module>
    filter[k][j] = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]'
```

**Input**

```
filter = []

for k in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        filter[k][j] = int(input())
```

What could be the reason?
Is there a more efficient way in creating matrices from scratch. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

---

Hackerrank presents your input as one string:

```
'[[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]'
```

not as sinlge integers followed by a return.

You need to take one string, then split it. Easiest way  would be `literal_eval` to create the full list of lists by this string input.

```
from ast import literal_eval

inp = "[[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]"  # use input() here

l = literal_eval(inp)

print(l) 
print(type(l))
```

wich will print:

```
[[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
<class 'list'>
```

---

Your code can't run fine as is - it would give you an index error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "whatever.py", line 5, in <module>
    filter[k][j] = int(input())
IndexError: list index out of range
```

[image: image of live test on pyfiddle.io]

because you try to access elements of your list that are not yet there:

> ```
> filter = []
>
> for k in range(3):
>     for j in range(3):
>         filter[k][j] = int(input())
> ```

`filter` is an empty list, you cannot access/index into `filter[0][0]` - you would need to change it to

```
filter = []

for k in range(3):
    # add a new empty list
    filter.append([])   
    for j in range(3):
        # add stuff to the last list of filter
        filter[-1].append( int(input()) )
```

Comment: Thanks alot Patrick. And the code i've written, it does run fine on a text editor, i encourage you to try once and check for yourself.

Comment: @aditya The code you did can not run - if it runs, you omitted part of your code or posted something different. You can copy/paste your code into `https://pyfiddle.io/` and try yourself. Change the python version to 3.6 and put some input into the "Program input" on top - see the screenshot on how to set it up

Comment: Oh my bad, there's actually one line before the iterations which i missed. Thank you Patrick!